# How to add only unique options to datalist element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch a set of objects from a server and add their attributes as options to a datalist element whenever a user clicks on the input field. I want to display unique options in the list only, however, anytime the input field comes into focus, my code will keep adding every option to the datalist even though I am making a check for it not to do so.

```
        <form action="">
        <label for="">Step 1: Select or create a theme: </label>
        <input type="input" list="themes" name="themes" onfocus="fetchThemes()" />
        <datalist id="themes">
        </datalist>
    </form>

    <script>
        let host = "http://localhost:3002"

        function fetchThemes(){
            fetch(host + "/contents")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => addToDatalist(data))
        }

        function addToDatalist(data){
            let datalist = document.getElementById('themes');

            for (let object of data){
                let option = document.createElement("option")
                option.value = object.name
                if (datalist.contains(option) === false){
                    datalist.appendChild(option)
                } 
            }
            console.log(document.getElementById('themes'))
        }

    </script>
```

I know i'm missing something small, but im not sure what it is that i'm doing wrong. Are DOM elements similar to objects in Python or Java, where even though two objects can have the same values, they're considered different since they are stored in separate memory locations? How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: You're checking for (strict) equality between two different elements, so that's not going to work. Easier to remove duplicates from the `data` array before you start creating `option` elements.

Comment: i think you have to check the whole list of option once again before adding the option. i hope you get my point !!

Answer (score 0):

i have made two arrays, first one is the check the array which contains all the unique values and the second one is the response of the server "object".

here i am comparing all the values of the check array with the one value of the object to get the unique value !!!

i hope this helps you !!!

//consider object as an array of the options and you want to include only the unique one 
    var check = []

```
var object = []
for(const i=0;i<=object.length;i++)
{
    for(const j=0;j<=check.length;j++)
    {
        if(check[j] ===option[i])
        {
        console.log("Value exists")
        }
        else{
            option.value = check[j]
        }
    }
}

for(const i=0;i<=check.length;i++)
{
    option.value = check[i]
}
```